# Substitution Cipher Help: Can't figure out keyword

Tags: substitution-cipher, playfair

Given a keyword, you can encrypt a message using alphabetical substitution like this:

```
plain: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
cipher: C I P H E R A B D F G J K L M N O Q S T U V W X Y Z
result: C A K S Y I B L T Z P D M U H F N V E G O W R J Q X
```

My problem is my professor literally never covered this topic and is putting on our upcoming exam. The example problem he gave us is as follows...

> Use your knowledge of Substitution Ciphers to find the keyword:
>
> UZQSOVUOHXMOPVGPOZPEVSGZWSZOPFPESXUDBMETSXAIZ
>   itwasdisclosedyesterdaythatseveralinformalbut
>
> VUEPHZHMDZSHZOWSFPAPPDTSVPQUZWYMXUZUHSX
>   directcontactshavebeenmadewithpolitical
>
> EPYEPOPDZSZUFPOMBZWPFUPZHMDJUDTMOHMQ
>   representativesofthevietconginmoscow

I have tried using frequency analysis of the ciphertext, I found that the most common plaintext letters for the keyword are "e","t", "i", "a", and possible "o" and "c".

Is there something I am missing?

EDIT: Looking online, I learned this is something called a Playfair cipher. Still cannot solve it though :( i don't know why I am having so much trouble with this.

Comment: You can just find a letter, say t and find it will be substituted by Z. So the letter at the position of t - let's call it k - is Z - t as t + k = Z and therefore k = Z - t. And that's all she wrote.

Comment: Playfair works with pairs of letters and is quite different than the monoalphabetic substitution you have here

Comment: @EugeneStyer anyway you can help me out?

Comment: Can you please read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher#Cryptanalysis) and explain what parts exactly you don't understand / know to apply?